# Как запустить 2 команды после поиска файлов командой find

Tags: linux, bash

Появилась необходимость архивировать файлы старше 7 дней. Делаю это при помощи `bzip2`. Но в нем нет встроенного удаления файла, после архивации.

Поэтому нужно сначала заархивировать, а после удалить заархивированный файл. Я знаю, что это можно сделать при помощи 2 отдельных команд, но уверен, что можно и одной (дабы не занимать в crontab много места)

Answer (score 2):

Немного покопавшись нашёл, как использовать 2 команды с `find`. В этом помогает параметр `-exec`:

```bash
find /home/user/logs -type f -name '*log' -mtime +7 -exec bash -c "bzip2 -k {}; rm {}" \;
```

Пояснения:

- `/home/user/logs` - каталог, в котором мы ищем файлы
- `-type f` - искать только файлы
- `-mtime +7` - файлы, которые старше 7 дней
- `-exec bash -c` - оболочка под которой будут запускаться следующие команды
- `"bzip2 -k {}; rm {}"` - список команда, запускаемых поочерёдно (будут применяться к каждому файлу по отдельности

---

К примеру, в директории `/home/user/logs` хранятся следующие файлы:

```bash
result_program_1.log
result_program_2.log
result_program_3.log
result_program_4.log
result_program_5.log
```

Первые три файла, старше 7 дней, так что выполнение вышеописанной команды `find` в результате будет выглядеть так:

```bash
bzip2 -k result_program_1.log
rm result_program_1.log

bzip2 -k result_program_2.log
rm result_program_2.log

bzip2 -k result_program_3.log
rm result_program_3.log
```